Google auth in local host gives "Unsecured login_uri provided" error
I am trying to incorporate google auth in my web app, however, when I try it locally, I get this error
[GSI_LOGGER]: Error parsing configuration from HTML: Unsecured login_uri provided.
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>

<div id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="client-id"
    data-context="signin"
    data-login_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback/google"
    data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin" data-locale="en"
 data-type="standard"
 data-shape="rectangular"
 data-theme="outline"
 data-text="signin_with"
 data-size="large"
 data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>

My understanding is that google auth requires https but not from local hosts, so why is it returning unsecured login_uri error?
I can't use localhost because I get this error instead The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID

